# Xamarin estimote beaconManager.StartTelemetryDiscovery(); caused exception You need to initialize SDK first

Tags: xamarin, initialization, estimote, telemetry

When start `beaconManager.StartTelemetryDiscovery();` in xamarin
caused this exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: You need to initialize SDK first.
>   EstimoteSDK.initialize(applicationContext, appId, appToken)

I can not find any method in the `extimotesdk` that calls for initialization.
I need to retrieve the battery and the temperature from the proximity beacon.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the sdk to be able to work  with it. take a look in the next link to know how to do it. https://community.estimote.com/hc/en-us/articles/203607313-What-are-App-ID-and-App-Token-and-what-do-I-need-them-for-

Comment: Ok, I know I have to initialize it but there is no initialize method on xamarin sdk.
EstimoteSDK.initialize (applicationContext, "YOUR APP ID", "YOUR APP TOKEN");

Xamarin estimotesdk by android does not have the initialize method

Answer (score 0):

In the old library there was no need to initialize and could pick up telemetry values (battery and temperature) directly from parameter P0.

The need I have is taking the battery and temperature value from the device